# Android Bitmap.Compress gives byte[] with -1 bytes?

Tags: c#, java, android, json, arrays

This is driving me a little bit mad!

I have taken an image and use the Bitmap.Compress method to get the image into a byte array (as below)

```
InputStream is = MyActivity.this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2; //try to decrease decoded image
options.inPurgeable = true; //purgeable to disk
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, bos);
myModel.setFullImage(bos.toByteArray());
```

However, when i take a look at the first few bytes of the byte[] it contains numerous -1 as well as valid numbers (0-255) and negative numbers like -98 etc.

I'm then sending this data across the wire (in json format) and it fails to convert it into a c# byte[] becuase of the negative numbers in the array.

what is going wrong or have i missed something.  I have even tried setting the compression fator to 0 in case the compress was doing something.

The strange thing is if i convert the bytes to base64 then transmit that i can then successfully convert the base64 string into a byte[] in c# as save the image.

Whats going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's `byte` is signed (it doesn't have unsigned types), while C#'s `byte` is unsigned (there is a separate `sbyte` for signed bytes); so two immediate options appear:

- use base-64 which will be immune to confusion
- read the data as `sbyte[]` in the C#, then just cast the values to `byte` (per item)

I'd probably use the base-64 option as it should also be smaller than representing them as numbers on the wire, but as an example of the convert:

```
sbyte[] orig = ...
byte[] munged = Array.ConvertAll(orig, x => (byte)x);
```

(add `unchecked` if you are using checked contexts, but this is rare; unchecked is the default and mire common option).

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'll give this a go but i was under the impression base64 increased the size rather than reduced it which why i just wanted to send a plain byte array.

Comment: @Jon: BASE64 *does* increase the size (as compared to the raw bytes), but JSON increases the size even more, so BASE64 should be a smaller encoding than JSON.

Comment: @Jon as Gabe notes - you aren't sending a raw byte[] - you are sending text; and integers as text are *much* bigger than base-64